# Visual Studio Palette Window Background

Tags: fonts, colors, visual-studio

So Visual Studio has tons of options for fonts and colors; but I can't seem to find the background/foreground colors for certain windows, such as:

- Solution Explorer
- Error List
- Test Results
- Pending Changes
- Properties

I find it strange I can change Output and Immediate but not these ones. Is there a place to change these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008.
Test Results use setting 'Environment Font' :( So if you want see fixed width font in Test Results you will see same font on source tabs and tool window captions...

Comment: This is pretty sad -- I'd really like to have my test result trace output as mono spaced.  pff.